# WiX ignores a condition in a fragment?

Tags: wix

I compile and link two .wxs files with candle/light (v 3.11).  The second .wxs file is a fragment:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='Windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <Fragment Id='PrerequisitesFragment'>
    <Condition Message="This application is supported only in Windows 7.">
      <![CDATA[(VersionNT = 601)]]>
    </Condition>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

My understanding is that a condition in a fragment counts as a launch condition, but this condition doesn't fail on Windows 10.  However, if I move the condition out of the fragment and in to the other .wxs file containing the Product, the condition works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing references the fragment, it won't end up in the .msi at all.

Comment: Thanks.  Apparently there was a mechanism for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978066/how-to-include-fragments-in-wix